# How to bind data only if form is submitted in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I have a form in Angular2.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   <button>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

`userName` and `onSubmit()` are defined in my component class. Now, when the form is opened, the user can either 'submit' the form or 'cancel' any update.

Suppose initial `userName` is `'abc'`.

1) User opens the form

2) Changes `userName` input to `'xyz'`

3) Clicks on `Cancel` button to cancel the changes

4) Opens the form again to see that `userName` is now `'xyz'`

I understand that its happening due to two way data binding, but I want to avoid it here. I want to update the property only if submit is clicked, else dismiss all the updates. How can I achieve this? Is there some angular way? Else should I maintain a deep copy myself?

Thanks!

Comment: See the discussion about the RestoreService here:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thanks. That helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using angular FormBuilder ,

The reference blog post - [Angular Form data driven](https://se-tech-tips.blogspot.com/2016/05/angular2-bind-data-only-if-form-is.html)

Sample source code - [GitHub](https://github.com/ishara/bind-data-only-if-form-is-submitted)

Comment: Thank You! Will try and get back.